# Excel web query escape characters for parameters

Tags: html, excel, http, url, excel-web-query

I am trying to load a table data into excel using web query.

The URL used has special characters in the parameter names.

Have tried using the encoded values of the characters but still no luck in opening the iqy file in excel. Throws invalid file format error.

Example URL:
[https://app.com/servers/details/test?OpenEmails[dateFrom]=["Start Date","Enter the start date"]&OpenEmails[dateTo]=["End Date","Enter the end date"]](http://Example%20URL)

Encoded values of the characters used:

```
%5B for [ 
%5D for ]
```

Also, used the "\" escape character.

How can I escape these characters in my web query (.iqy) file?

**Edit 1:** Used VBA instead of web query and its working fine.

Comment: Have you tried the entities for brackets?  &#91; and &#93;

Comment: @SammyB : Yes, I did. No luck with them as well.